# Open URL in same window from different tabs

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this function in a javascript on my web page that loads a url from an textfield with id url:

```
function loadUrl() 
{
    var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    window.open(url, 'urlwindow');
}
```

If I open two tabs in my browser and opens my web page in both tabs, I want both tabs to open the url in the same window, not two separate windows. Is this possible?

In other words, I want to target window opened from another tab.

Comment: Post code or give example because your question isn't quite clear...

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the behaviur of the user's browser: just add as target windows "_blank" and hope your user have enough recent web client that opens a new tab and not a new window.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this works perfectly (and just like you're trying to do it) with Firefox and IE, but not with Chrome or Safari.

Firefox and IE seem to use domain-specific namespaces for target names, while Chrome and Safari seem to use browser tab-specific namespaces for target names, so in these two browsers, 'urlwindow' as seen from tab A is different from 'urlwindow' as seen from tab B.

I'm trying to find a workaround for this myself, but have not yet been successful. See [Chrome/Safari: how to open the same window from different tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175028/chrome-how-to-open-the-same-window-from-different-tabs-or-windows)