# Chrome/Safari: how to open the same window from different tabs or windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, target, window.open, log4javascript

In a web application, I have an optional popup window into which logging content is being loaded. This window is opened via Javascript using `window.open()`.

The users typically have multiple tabs of the application open and my intention is to always reuse the same popup window (if currently open), no matter from which tab they trigger the popup. To do so, I use code similar to this to open the popup:

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("popup.html", "my_popup", "width=600,height=400,status,resizable");
    }
    </script>
```

This works fine in Firefox and IE - only a single popup window is ever opened and all content that I want to log is being loaded into that window.

Chrome and Safari however, use different popup windows depending on the tab from which the popup is launched.

I assumed that the second parameter of `window.open()` specifies a target name from a global namespace, which seems to be the case for most browsers. But Chrome and Safari behave as if there were tab-specific namespaces for these target names, i.e. "my_popup" referenced from tab 1 refers to a different target than "my_popup" from tab 2. (to make things more complicated, tabs that have been "duplicated" seem to share the same namespace, i.e. they **do** reuse the same popup window, but tabs created otherwise don't.)

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior of Chrome and Safari and access the same popup window from all tabs that the user may have open?

Or do I have to assume that this is browser-specific behavior for which there seems to be no workaround?

I have tested this with various browsers:

IE 11.0.9600.18204
All tabs with content from the same domain open/reload a single shared popup window (i.e the target namespace seems to be local per domain).
All tabs with content from `file://` URLs reuse the same popup window as tabs with content from `http://` URLs that point to the local intranet.

Firefox 46.0.1
All tabs with content from the same domain open/reload a single shared popup window (i.e the target namespace seems to be local per domain).
All tabs with content from `file://` URLs use their own single shared popup window (i.e. `file://` URLs seem to have their own target namespace).

Edge 20.10240.16384.0
The behavior is inconsistent: in most of my tests, Edge behaved like Firefox, but occasionally like Chrome as well.
I don't have a problem in ignoring Edge for the time being.

Chrome 50.0.2661.94
Each tab opens or reloads its own popup window (i.e the target namespace seems to be local per tab)

Safari 9.1
Each tab opens or reloads its own popup window (i.e the target namespace seems to be local per tab)

By the way, in all of these browsers the behavior does not depend on whether or not the popup window was launched due to user interaction: the behavior is identical between cases where the popup is launched via `body onload()` and cases where it is loaded via `button onclick()`.

*[here's additional background information that I assume not to be relevant to the problem, but who knows... ;-)

Actually, our application does not directly open the popup windows, instead we're using log4javascript which opens a logging window (or in case of Chrome: multiple logging windows). I'm willing to extend the log4javascript code to deal with this and send a patch to the maintainer, but in order to do so I need to solve the basic problem described above]*

Comment: The target name can't be in a global namespace. That would allow applications from different domains to reuse each other's windows.

Comment: I understand the security implication, but I'm only interested in having different tabs/windows within the same domain reuse the same popup window (i.e. like Firefox and IE handle this). Arguably this case would not cause the problem you mention.

Comment: That's true, I was just addressing your point "I assumed that the second parameter specifies a target name from a global namespace". That's obviously not possible in general. Maybe it could be a per-domain namespace.

Comment: But per-domain namespaces could be a problem, too. Suppose you open multiple tabs on the same website, and it pops up a window. Would you really want the popup from tab 2 to replace the popup from tab 1?

Comment: More or less yes, that's what I want. The window would not be replaced, though. It would just be used from all tabs. So whenever our application wants to log something (no matter from which tab or browser window), the log output would appear in the same popup window. The user could then send us the output of that window for analysis.
Incidentally, this is exactly how it works in Firefox and IE. It's just that some of our users prefer to use Chrome but hate it when they get one popup window per open browser tab (They work in Salesforce.com and typically have dozens of tabs open).